# acos() bad results with two close points in C

Tags: c, math.h, rounding-error

I am making a function that calculates the distance of two points using their latitude/longitude (in degrees not radians) and the spherical law of cosines. The problem I have is that due to rounding errors in the function `acos()` the results I am obtaining are far from good when the two points are very close to each other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct{
 double lat;
 double lon;
} point;

#define DEG_TO_RAD 0.017453292519943295769236907684886
#define EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS 6372797.560856

double distance(point a, point b) {
  double arg=sin(a.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * sin(b.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) + cos(a.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cos(b.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cos((a.lon-b.lon) * DEG_TO_RAD);
  if(arg>1) arg=1;
  else if (arg<-1) arg=-1;
  printf("arg=%.12f acos(arg)=%.12f\n",arg, acos(arg));    //to see the problem
  return acos(arg) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS;
}

int main(){
  point p1,p2;

  p1.lat=63.0;
  p1.lon=27.0;
  p2.lat=p1.lat;
  p2.lon=p1.lon;

  printf("dist=%.8f\n",distance(p1,p2));

  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
arg=1.000000000000 acos(arg)=0.000000014901
dist=0.09496208
```

as you can see, when it computes the `acos()` it should give zero but it does give some errors that get enormously magnified after multiplying by the earth radius. It also happens when the two points are not equal but very close. If it is of any use my data about latitude and longitude has up to 7 decimal digits.

Comment: You might want to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). In short, it's not possible to get exact representations of some numbers, so you will always have rounding problems. You can alleviate some of them by using a larger precision type, like `long double`.

Comment: This isn't a problem with `acos`; the problem is that `arg` is not exactly `1.0`.

Comment: Side note: `<math.h>` contains definitions for various mathematical constants, so you can define `#define DEG_TO_RAD M_PI/180.0` instead.

Comment: A format that displays enough digits to distinguish all double-precision numbers is `%.16e`. When you use `%.12f`, you may get the impression that `arg` is zero when it isn't.

Comment: When the points are close together the curvature of the earth can be ignored and you can apply Pythagoras.  You just need to apply a scaling factor to longitude, based on latitude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result you get from `acos` is as good as it gets: the problem is that the calculation of `arg` will always have a small error and return a value that is slightly off. When the two points are equal or very close the result is less than one, for example 1-10<sup>-16</sup>. If you look at [the graph of `acos(x)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acos%28x%29) you'll see that it's nearly vertical at x=1, which means that even the slightest error in `arg` has a huge impact on the relative error. In other words, the algorithm is numerically unstable.

You can use the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to get better results.

Comment: This one seems to be obtaining better precision even using only double and not long double...

Comment: @gunbl4d3 Yes, knowledge of math usually beats knowledge of floating-point programming.

Comment: I'll take this solution. Only one has to make sure that the values within the square root are bounded between 0 and 1 and do not cross those boundaries due to floating point errors.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what [extended precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) is for: to compute intermediate results at a higher precision than the `double` precision used for arguments and results.

I changed your program thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

typedef struct{
 double lat;
 double lon;
} point;

#define DEG_TO_RAD 0.017453292519943295769236907684886L
#define EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS 6372797.560856L

double distance(point a, point b) {
  long double arg=sinl(a.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * sinl(b.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) + cosl(a.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cosl(b.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cosl((a.lon-b.lon) * DEG_TO_RAD);
  if(arg>1) arg=1;
  else if (arg<-1) arg=-1;
  printf("arg=%.20Le acos(arg)=%.20Le\n",arg, acosl(arg));
  return acosl(arg) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS;
}

int main(){
  point p1,p2;

  p1.lat=63.0;
  p1.lon=27.0;
  p2.lat=p1.lat;
  p2.lon=p1.lon;

  printf("precision of long double:%Le\n", LDBL_EPSILON);

  printf("dist=%.8f\n",distance(p1,p2));

  return 0;
}
```

With these changes, on a compiler that offers extended precision for `long double`, the result is as expected:

```
precision of long double:1.084202e-19
arg=1.00000000000000000000e+00 acos(arg)=0.00000000000000000000e+00
dist=0.00000000
```

### EDIT:

Here is a version that uses GCC's quadmath library for intermediate results. It requires a recent GCC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <quadmath.h>

typedef struct{
 double lat;
 double lon;
} point;

#define DEG_TO_RAD (M_PIq / 180)
#define EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS ((__float128)6372797.560856L)

double distance(point a, point b) {
  __float128 arg=sinq(a.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * sinq(b.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) + cosq(a.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cosq(b.lat * DEG_TO_RAD) * cosq((a.lon-b.lon) * DEG_TO_RAD);
  if(arg>1) arg=1;
  else if (arg<-1) arg=-1;
  printf("arg=%.20Le acos(arg)=%.20Le\n",(long double)arg, (long double)acosq(arg));
  return acosq(arg) * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS;
}

int main(){
  point p1,p2;

  p1.lat=63.0;
  p1.lon=27.0;
  p2.lat=p1.lat;
  p2.lon=p1.lon;

  printf("dist=%.8f\n",distance(p1,p2));

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled and ran with:

```
$ gcc-206231/bin/gcc t.c -lquadmath && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=gcc-206231/lib64 ./a.out
```

Comment: In windows I do not seem to have this `long double`... I am using MinGW.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 I was going to say something about the definition of `long double` as `double` on Windows. GCC has a software implementation of quad-precision. I will try to use it and update my answer with an example if I manage to: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath.pdf

Comment: @gunbl4d3 Done. The quadmath library is only part of recent enough GCC versions.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I could not implement it in my machine. I will take it into account when I am making code for Unix systems, where it worked properly or if I get a newer gcc version on windows.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this it's usually best to try to reformulate the problem
to avoid badly conditioned formulas like acos(*x*) with *x* small.  This is
a well-beaten problem in the case of distance computations on a sphere
and better formulations are provided on the [Great-circle page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulas) on
Wikipedia.  These give high accuracy for short distances with ordinary
double precision arithmetic.